# How to prove the inequality $a^2b^2\ge16(a-1)(b-1)$ if $a>1$ and $b>1$

Tags: inequality

I'm stuck on proving that $a^2b^2\ge16(a-1)(b-1)$ if $a>1$ and $b>1$.

I've tried to rearrange into a square without any success.

Comment: Please add what you have done...

Comment: So i've tried to expand the 16(a-1)(b-1) and shift it to the left but I cant find a square, I don't know what else to try. I've also tried splitting it into cases without success.

Comment: @AlexM Please, show me, what exactly did you do?

Comment: Ive gotten $a^2b^2-16ab+16a+16b-116\ge0$ but i am trying to factorise it into a square but I still haven't seen one. Also, I've managed to prove the case where both a and b are greater than 2.

Comment: @AlexM It should be $a^2b^2-16ab+16a+16b-16$ and  indeed it's a square. Try more.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I'm sorry but I still dont see the square.

Comment: @AlexM Post your attempts in your topic. Write, how exactly  you tried to get a sum of squares. and I'll show my solution. Otherwise, you topic would be deleted and I don't want that my solution would be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to show that, if $x > 1,$ then $\frac{x^2}{x-1} \geq 4.$

Suppose $x>1.$ Then, since $(x-2)^2 \geq 0,$ it follows that $x^2 \geq 4x - 4 = 4(x-1), \overset{x-1 > 0}{\implies} \frac{x^2}{x-1} \geq 4.$

Answer (score 1):

Use $\frac{1}{2}(A+\frac{1}{A})\geq 1$ and denote $A^2=a-1, B^2=b-1.$